# In my DOM, my xpath identified two elements, one element is clickable and other is not. How to find which element is clickable using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My DOM is loading duplicate elements, i need to click on element which is clickable and another is not clickable. Wait statement doesn't help in this situation. which loop and conditions will be useful in selenium

Comment: can you share the html code for the both elements?

Answer (score 1):

Try this pseudocode example, get all of Your elements in list, and iterate them in loop, and check which one is able to click,

```
List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElements(by some locator);

for (WebElement element : listElements){

    if(element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()){

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2); 
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable());
        element.click();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: +1 for a neat solution but this should rarely be used. You should be able to identify unique xpath for your desired element instead.

Comment: Agreed. This is how to do it, but if You could avoid it, please try.